# How to add Mate Listeners using Action Script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, popup, mate-flex-framework

in one of my forms, I have used the following code for adding Mate Listeners

```
<mate:Listener type="{DBEvent.Update_Result}" receive="{onUpdateResults(event)}"/>
```

I am displaying this form as a popup. What happening is, for the first time, onUpdateResults method executed only once as expected. Then i close the popup and reopened it. This time onUpdateResults method called twice, then next 4time and so on...

After so much of googling, i found that Mate Listeners are still active, even though we remove/close the popup. I tried weak references, close the popup using PopupManager.RemovePopup and so on. Nothing worked.

Then i thought of registering and unregistering the mate listeners manually using action script. So, i have tried the following code

```
var _listener:Listener= new Listener();

_listener.addEventListener(DBEvent.Update_Result,onUpdateResults);
```

to unregister...

```
_listener.removeEventListener(DBEvent.Update_Result,onUpdateResults);
```

But this is also not working.

Please somebody help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Create runtime popup windows in main application:

```
PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, MyPopUp, true);
```

MyPopUp - mx:TitleWindow from MyPopUp.mxml
Add any listeners in OnInit in MyPopUp.mxml:

```
_listener.addEventListener(DBEvent.Update_Result, onUpdateResults);
```

Close popup when you click any button (button's click event or any):

```
PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
```